# Insert two or more Comma separated values in table using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want try to insert Two variable in table the value is separated with comma but i don't know how i can insert it

My situation is below

I create temp table

```
create table #temp (sku varchar(10), qty int)
```

now declare two variable with value

```
declare @sku varchar(200) = 'RCLET0005,RCLET0015';
declare @qty varchar(100) = '2,1';
```

now i want insert this variable in #temp table
I have split function.
I tried Below query

```
insert into #temp (sku,qty) values
((select value from [dbo].[fn_Split](@sku, ',')),
(select value from [dbo].[fn_Split](@qty, ',')))
```

Comment: what is the output of split function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fn_Split function needs to return the ordinal position of each value so that the separate lists can be correlated. Below is an example using a derived table subquery. You could also use CTEs or CROSS APPLY.

```
INSERT INTO #temp (sku,qty) 
SELECT 
      sku.value
    , qty.value
FROM (SELECT ordinal_position, value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@sku, ',') AS sku
JOIN (SELECT ordinal_position, value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@qty, ',') AS qty ON
    sku.ordinal_position = qty.ordinal_position;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this..

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY null) as rn, value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@sku, ',')
    UNION
    SELECT 2+(row_number() OVER(ORDER BY null)) as rn, value FROM [dbo].[fn_Split](@qty, ',')
)

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT c1.value,c2.value
FROM cte c1 
    INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.rn = c1.rn+1 AND c1.rn IN (1,3) AND c2.rn IN (2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are not repeated in each string and your split function doesn't return the position, you can do:

```
with s as (
      select value,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as pos
      from dbo.fn_Split(@sku, ',')
     ),
     q as (
      select value,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as pos
      from dbo.fn_Split(@qty, ',')
     )
insert into #temp (sku,qty)
    select s.value, q.value
    from s join
         q
         on s.pos = q.pos;
```

The following CTEs would probably work without those assumptions -- but because the ordering is not stable, the code is not *guaranteed* to work:

```
with s as (
      select value,
             row_number() over (order by charindex(value, @sku)) as pos
      from dbo.fn_Split(@sku, ',')
     ),
     q as (
      select value,
             row_number() over (order by charindex(value, @qty)) as pos
      from dbo.fn_Split(@qty, ',')
     )
```

The alternative solutions don't use `fn_split()`.  They would use recursive CTEs or XML.